# Java Program, String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

It's about string to make a compact output.

**Example 1**

```
Input : boooooob
Output : bob
```

**Example2**

```
Input : boobaabbiibbuuuuub
Output : bobabibub
```

Can anyone help me?

I'm stuck, thx.

Comment: stuck where, show that..!! Just simply posting the question will not help..!!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved by using regular expression `(\\w)\\1+`

```
public class RemoveReplicateLetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //For input: boooooob
        System.out.println(removeReplicateLetter("boooooob"));
        //For input: boobaabbiibbuuuuub
        System.out.println(removeReplicateLetter("boobaabbiibbuuuuub"));
    }

    public static String removeReplicateLetter(String word) {
        /*
         REGEX: 
         (\\w)\\1+ 
         - \\w  : matches any word character (letter, digit, or underscore)
         - \\1+ : matches whatever was in the first set of parentheses, one or more times.
         */
        return word.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1+", "$1");
        //Here $1 means return letter with match in word by regex.
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bob
bobabibub
```

Answer (score 2):

This method should do the job:

```
public String simplify(String input) {
    // Convert to an array for char based comparison
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
    // First char will always be included in the output because there is no char to compete
    String output = String.valueOf(inputArray[0]);

    // Check every char against the following
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        // If not equal
        if (inputArray[i - 1] != inputArray[i]) {
            // Add to output
            output += inputArray[i];
        }
    }

    // Return the result
    return output;
}
```

It will compare every char with the following one and only adds it to the output if they are not equal.

**Note:** This is just a proof of concept, not an optimal solution.

Comment: Good edit. The other way? thing? I was thinking of was starting at `int i = 1`.